# What is Tarha Acharona?

Tags: trop-cantillation

Found this picture in this latin book. It seems to distinguish between a tarha and a tarha aharona. Any ideas what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

R' Zalman of Hanau writes (*Shaare Zimra*, gate 2, [paragraph 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30699&pgnum=15)):

> There are other helper accents that are not so common in Scripture but appear occasionally and are listed in the Mesorah. They are *yareach ben yomo*, *mer'cha ch'fula*, and *m'ay'la*.

He then describes the first two of those and then, in [paragraph 7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30699&pgnum=16), continues:

> *M'ay'la* looks like a *tip'cha* [=*tarcha*]. It's found in five places on a word that has a *sof pasuk* and in ten places on a word that has an *esnachta*, in the location for a *meseg*. It's also found in eighteen places before a *zarka*, but then it looks like a *mer'cha* and in a separate word.

He goes on to list, from the Mesorah, where these appear. Those in the Pentateuch are Gen. 8:18 "וַיֵּ֖צֵא־נֹ֑חַ", Lev. 21:4 "לְהֵ֖חַלּֽוֹ", Numbers 15:21 "לְדֹרֹ֖תֵיכֶֽם", and Numbers 28:26 "בְּשָׁבֻעֹ֖תֵיכֶ֑ם".

I'm guessing that that's what your book is referring to when it lists *tarcha acharona* among the helper accents, since the *m'ay'la* (a) is a helper accent, (b) looks like a *tip'cha* (=*tarcha*), and (c) is in some sense *acharona* (last), specifically in that it is on the last word of the (half-)*pasuk*.

Comment: Wait, I've never heard that mercha zarka business!  There's a mercha before a zarka in lots of places.  Do you know what he's referring to?

Comment: Let's continue this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/vdibarta-bam), @Heshy.